# Angular 5 ngClass with a if

Tags: angular

This is my code for a row in a table

```
  <tr class="user-item" *ngFor="let device of group.devices" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" ngClass="device.onlineState == 'Offline' ? 'highlight' : 'highlight2'">
    <td class="qkFix">{{ device.deviceId }}</td>
    <td class="qkFix">{{ device.alias }}</td>
    <td class="qkFix" *ngIf="device.onlineState == 'Online'" ngClass="colorOnline">{{ device.onlineState }}
      <span class="dotOnline"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="qkFix" *ngIf="device.onlineState == 'Offline'" ngClass="colorOffline">{{ device.onlineState }}
      <span class="dotOffline"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="qkFix">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); showDevice(device); editDeviceDialog()">
        <i class="material-icons">{{ (auth.hasPermissions(['update-devices'], true)) ? 'edit' : 'open_in_new'}}</i>
      </button>
      <button [disabled]="!(auth.hasPermissions(['delete-devices'], true))" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();deleteDevice(device)">
        <i *ngIf="(auth.hasPermissions(['delete-devices'], true))" class="material-icons" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();deleteDevice(device)">delete</i>
        <i *ngIf="!(auth.hasPermissions(['delete-devices'], true))" class="material-icons" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">delete</i>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="device.onlineState == 'Online'" [disabled]="!(auth.hasPermissions(['remote-control'], true))" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); remoteSession(device)">
        <i *ngIf="(auth.hasPermissions(['remote-control'], true))" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();remoteSession(device)" class="material-icons">swap_horiz</i>
        <i *ngIf="!(auth.hasPermissions(['remote-control'], true))" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="material-icons">swap_horiz</i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Specific ngClass code

```
ngClass="device.onlineState == 'Offline' ? 'highlight' : 'highlight2'"
```

**I want the row to have the class** `highlight` **if the onlineState of that device is  Offline.** `device.onlineState either returns Online or Offline`. **If the onlineState is Online it shouldn't have a class.**

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want, are you saying using `ngClass` is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `ngClass` in brackets i.e. `[ngClass]`. [For more details](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

**Answer:**

```
 [ngClass]="device.onlineState == 'Offline' ? 'highlight' : 'highlight2'"
```

If you want to add `multiple classes` you can do like this:

**option1:**

```
 [ngClass]="condition ? 'class1 class2 class3' : 'class4 class5 class6'"
```

**Option2:**

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': condition1, 'class2': Condition2}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
  [class.highlight]="device.onlineState == 'Offline'"
```

And you already have to do `[ngClass]` instead of `ngClass` to allow the execution of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

ngClass is a directive that accept an object as argument with the name of your classes as properties and conditions as values, exemple:

```
[ngClass]="{'highlight': device.onlineState === 'Offline'}"
```

You add multiple classes like this:

```
[ngClass]="{'highlight other-class': device.onlineState === 'Offline'}"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="{'highlight': device.onlineState === 'Offline', 'other-class': condition}"
```